# How i can get value form select > option, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with get value form select > option.
I make  option that:

```
$.each(response, function(i, element) 
 { 
   var nazwaKategori = element.name;
   var idKategori = element.id;
    $("#kategoria").append("<option>KategoriaID:" + idKategori + ", Nazwa Kategorii:" + nazwaKategori + "</option>");
 });
```

In body:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label  align="center" for="text">Lista dostępnych kategorii.</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="kategoria">
        <div id="kategoria">
        </div>
        </select>
        <div id="wypisz"><div>
   </div> 
</form>
```

And i get this option:

```
<script>
   $( "#kategoria" ).change(function () {
    var str = "";
      $( "#kategoria option:selected" ).each(function() {
       str += $(this.KategoriaID).val() + " ";
      });
   $( "#wypisz" ).text( str );
 })
.change();
</script>
```

How i can get only idKategori ? I musc find pattern in get text?
Thanks

Comment: Woah! Why the `div` inside a `select`? Did you mean for that to be an `option`?

Comment: When I chose one of options, I would like to get from only ID. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apart of having a wrong html structure with a `div` inside a `select`, when you are creating your dropdown, you could use something like this:

```
$("#kategoria").append("<option value='"+idKategori+"'>KategoriaID:" + idKategori + ", Nazwa Kategorii:" + nazwaKategori + "</option>");
```

So every option will have a value and then in the change event you could use this:

```
$( "#kategoria" ).on("change", function () {
    var optionselected = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    //HEre you will have you value of the option selected in a variable
    console.log(optionselected);

});
```

I don't know if thats what you wanted, and I don't know if your dropdown creation is working, but your questions is to get value from select option with jquery. Hope this helps